# DOJO AJAX Request asking for OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, dojo

I have exposed a simple RESTful JSON url via CherryPy (Python web framework). I have a second application (using Pylons) which needs to reach a URL exposed by CherryPy. Both are being served via localhost. Both URLs resolve just fine when using a browser directly.

But, when a DOJO script running from the initial Pylons request invokes the JSON url from CherryPy, it fails. I open LiveHeaders in Firefox and find that DOJO is first sending an HTTP "OPTIONS" request. CherryPy refuses the OPTIONS request with a 405, Method Not Allowed and it all stops.

If I drop this same page into the CherryPy application, all is well.

What is the best way to resolve this on my localhost dev platform? .... and will this occur in Prod?

Answer (score 3):

On a different site I found that you need to override the xhrArgs' headers to prevent this issue. I quote from that forum:

> It looks like by default dojo adds an 'X-Requested-With' argument to the Access-Control-Request-Header property, which typically causes servers to reject the request because it causes cross-site XHR requests to force preflight requests.

The original solution [is here](http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/3960.page).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be you are serving these two apps locally via 2 different ports, which is making dojo try to execute a cross-domain XHR call.

You need to be able to serve the JSON URL from the same URL (protocol, hostname, & port) to make a successful XHR call.  I do this by using nginx locally, and configuring it to serve the database requests from my Dojo application by forwarding them to CouchDB.